# My date filter is not working properly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the view I am using to retrieve the data in my UI. The problem with this is that when I look data between `2021-03-09' and '2021-03-17`, it returns the result from `2021-03-18` as well.

I had look into `Postman` to check what date it is passing through and found that it sending date like `startDateTime%20ge%202021-03-08T12:00:00.000Z%20and%20startDateTime%20le%202021-03-17T12:00:00.000Z` which returns `2021-03-18` data as well. I do not want it to return the 18th one. Is there any way to modify in the script. But If search for 2021-03-18 date range like `startDateTime%20ge%202021-03-17T12:00:00.000Z%20and%20startDateTime%20le%202021-03-18T12:00:00.000Z`, it returns correct number of row.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_o_sessions]
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        NEWID() AS TUniqueKey,
        SNumber AS Sessionid,
        CSession,
        SStartDateTime AS StartDateTime,
    FROM
        [vw_o_appointments]
    where ClinicCode='abc1'
   and SStartDateTime between '2021-03-09' and '2021-03-17'
    GROUP BY
        SSessionNumber,     
        CSession, 
        SStartDateTime,
```

The other view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_o_appointments]
AS
    SELECT
        NEWID() AS TUniqueKey,
        CASE 
           WHEN (PE.EAdmitDateTime IS NOT NULL 
                 AND CAST(PE.EAdmitDateTime AS time) < '12:30') OR  
                (CAST(PE.ADate AS time) < '12:30') 
             then convert(varchar(8), isnull(Pe.EAdmitDateTime, PE.ADate),112 ) + '0'
           WHEN (PE.EAdmitDateTime IS NOT NULL 
                 AND CAST(PE.EAdmitDateTime AS time) >= '12:30') 
                OR (CAST(PE.ADate AS time) > '12:30') 
              then convert(varchar(8), isnull(Pe.EAdmitDateTime, PE.ADate),112) + '1'
           ELSE NULL
        END AS SNumber,
        CONVERT(date, ISNULL(Pe.EAdmitDateTime, PE.ADate)) AS SStartDateTime,
        CASE 
            WHEN (PE.EAdmitDateTime IS NOT NULL 
                  AND CAST(PE.EAdmitDateTime AS time) < '12:30') 
                 OR (CAST(PE.ADate AS time) < '12:30') 
                THEN 'AM'
            WHEN (PE.EAdmitDateTime IS NOT NULL 
                  AND CAST(PE.EAdmitDateTime AS time) >= '12:30') 
                 OR (CAST(PE.ADate AS time) > '12:30') 
                THEN 'PM'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS CSession  
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             PE1.PNumber,
             PE1.REncounterId,
             PE1.ADate,
             PE1.EAdmitDateTime,
             PE1.MType
         FROM
             (SELECT
                  PNumber,
                  REncounterId,
                  ADate,
                  EAdmitDateTime,
                  MType
              FROM
                  PEncounter
              WHERE 
                  PNumber IS NOT NULL) AS PE1
         LEFT JOIN
             PExtendedAttr PEA ON PE1.REncounterId = PEA.REncounterId   
         LEFT JOIN 
             PBooking PB ON PB.REncounterId = PE1.REncounterId) AS PE
```

Here is the sample data from the database. When I run a query in the database, it returns the correct number of rows. The problem occurs only when I make a request through `Postman` or application UI.

```
TUniqueKey  Clinic  CSession           StartDateTime
----------------------------------------------------
8CE5DE47    ABC1        AM               2021/03/11
56F3E7B2    ABC1        AM               2021/03/15
96E8BFE4    ABC1        AM               2021/03/10
97ACF31E    ABC1        PM               2021/03/11
22CAE64E    ABC1        PM               2021/03/15
B14DB9EA    ABC1        PM               2021/03/18
B14DB9EC    ABC1        AM               2021/03/18
```

Comment: Please show the `SELECT` query and sample data

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, edited question. When I select query, it returns a correct number of rows but problem occurs when trying to retrieve through `Postman`.

Comment: @user10216769 I can't see any `where` clause in the above SQL which compares dates?

Comment: @DaleK, sorry. Just updated the question. Why it is time as well in postman. As you have seen the query, I am using `Date` only.

Comment: You have a number of `CONVERT(varchar, ..., 112)` usages in there. Are you expecting to converted values to be of type `varchar(8)` without specifying a length?

Comment: And how are you storing your dates? What datatype? Hopefully not varchar...

Comment: By the way, your views are unnecessarily verbose: first one has both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` unclear why you need them at all, but you only need one at most. The other has two nested derived tables which are unnecessary, and `CONVERT(varchar` without a length which is then converted again

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, modified the query, Please suggest me solution.

Comment: @DaleK, storing dates as datetime2(7).

Comment: @Charlieface, I need to display the rows based on group by date and other fields mentioned in the query. The nested query is needed to get the expected value.

Comment: To group by date `convert(date, someColumn)`. And no, you definitely don't need those nested queries, you can do it with a couple left joins and a where, those queries are not even changing any of the selected columns

Comment: @Charlieface, can you please provide me solution? I am looking forward to it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it: what is the query generated by Postman, you haven't shown it? Is it parameterized or are you inserting date literals? What does it have to do with the view `vw_o_sessions`?

Comment: @Charlieface, Just checking why there is a mismatch between the postman and the query itself. The date we are passing is the `date` but how come the request gets changed into `DateTime`.`filter=(startDateTime%20ge%202021-03-08T12:00:00.000Z%20and%20startDateTime%20le%202021-03-17T12:00:00.000Z)`